# Most optimal way to search for a signature in a file

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to learn about optimizing c++ code, so i have this project idea to create a "antivirus" program that searches for a special signature (virus) in a file hierarchy. I'm wondering if there is a better design when trying to optimize for speed than using ifstream and then writing to a `std::bitset<size_of_signature>` buffer and then comparing with the signature for a signature match or until the buffer has reached end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus programs don't work in a such way. They detect file types and work with each file type in different ways. For example they parse sections of a PE executable file and analyse only those sections that may contain virus signatures. This significantly reduces analyzing time.

Answer (score 0):

"*comparing with the signature for a signature match*" solution has O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity (file size × number of hashes).
It should be pretty simple to optimize it if you organize the search hashes in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure and apply a little bit of dynamic programming: iteratively reduce the search space by 1 byte, maintaining a list of hash subsequences found so far.

So:

- Load the file (or a part of it) into a `std::vector<uint8_t>`
- for each byte B in the vector:

  - for each subsequence S in the state:

    - if S+B is found in the trie:

      - if S+B is a full hash - print it and remove S from the state
      - else update S to S+B
    - else remove S from the state
  - if B is found in the trie:

    - add B to the state as a new subsequence

You can find more examples of this algorithm if you research a "*find the longest word in a collection*" type of problems.